# How can I get a correctly typed item from a collection of union types?

Tags: typescript, generics, collections

I'm writing a custom collection class that stores a union type. Now I want to have an accessor method that returns a correctly (single)-typed item. This is what I came up with:

```js
class GameA {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

class GameB {
    constructor(public numberOfTries: number) {}
}

type AllGames = GameA | GameB;

class GameCollection {
    store: Array<AllGames>;
    constructor() {
        this.store = [];
    }
    add(g: AllGames) {
        this.store.push(g)
    }
    get<T extends AllGames>(idx: number): T {
        const item = this.store[idx];
        if (typeof item === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error("Index out of bounds");
        }
        // Any way to check at runtime that item is of type T?
        return item as T;
    }
}

const store = new GameCollection()
store.add(new GameA('Anton'))
store.add(new GameB(42))

console.log('First item (has name):', store.get<GameA>(0).name)
console.log('Second item (name is undefined):', store.get<GameA>(1).name)
```

As you can see, when consuming code provides the wrong type, it will received `undefined` values. Is there any way to make this code more type safe?

I know that I'll probably need a runtime check, but I want to avoid having to call `instanceof` after every call to `get`.

Another option would be to add `get` methods for each type, but that would violate the open-closed principle because with every new type I'd also have to add a getter.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you looked into implementing your own type guards? See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: A signature like `get<T extends AllGames>(idx: number): T` [cannot possibly be implemented correctly](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1205170798282960896).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is using [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions), and changing the `get` function to actually take in a `type`. Providing the type as a generic instead will have no effect at runtime.

```js
// Making it so there's a `type` field that can be discriminated on at runtime 
class GameA {
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
  name: string
  type: 'GameA' = 'GameA'
}

class GameB {
  constructor(numberOfTries: number) {
    this.numberOfTries = numberOfTries
  }
  numberOfTries: number
  type: 'GameB' = 'GameB'
  name: undefined
}

type AllGames = GameA | GameB

class GameCollection {
  store: AllGames[]
  constructor() {
    this.store = []
  }
  add(g: AllGames) {
    this.store.push(g)
  }
  get(idx: number, type: AllGames['type']) { // updating so it takes a type argument that's available at runtime
    const item = this.store[idx]
    if (!item) {
      throw new Error('Index out of bounds')
    }

    if (item.type === type) {
      return item
    }
    throw new Error('No Game of type ' + type + ' at index ' + idx)
  }
}

const store = new GameCollection()
store.add(new GameA('Anton'))
store.add(new GameB(42))

console.log('First item (has name):', store.get(0, 'GameA').name) // name is correctly typed to undefined | string 
console.log('Second item (name is undefined):', store.get(1, 'GameA').name) // name is correctly typed to undefined | string
```

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to, you will need a runtime check.  TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when compiled to JavaScript, so the lines `store.get<GameA>(0)` and `store.get<GameB>(0)` both compile to `store.get(0)`.  This implies that there is no possible way for them to behave differently from each other.

Instead, you could change your `get()` method so it takes some type information as an actual runtime parameter instead of as only a type parameter.  The most straightforward thing to pass in is the constructor of the class instance you're trying to get:

```
get<T extends AllGames>(ctor: new (...args: any) => T, idx: number): T {
    const item = this.store[idx];
    if (typeof item === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error("Index out of bounds");
    }
    if (!(item instanceof ctor)) {
        throw new Error("Item is the wrong type");
    }
    return item;
}
```

The call isn't very different from before:

```
console.log('First item:', store.get(GameA, 0).name); // Anton
console.log('Second item:', store.get(GameA, 1).name); // runtime error
```

but now you'll get a runtime error as soon as you try to `get()` something of the wrong type.  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly, though.

---

Perhaps you'd like the *compiler* to give an error when you `get()` something of the wrong type, or even better, have the compiler *know* what the type will be when you call `get()`.  Meaning that when you call `store.add(new GameA('Anton'))`, the compiler will *modify* the type of `store` to remember that its argument at index `0` is a `GameA` and not a `GameB`.  This is possible with [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), although they're somewhat painful to use:

```
type Next = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
class GameCollection<N extends number = 0, A extends Record<number, AllGames> = {}> {
    store: Array<AllGames> & A;
    constructor() {
        this.store = [] as any;
    }
    add<T extends AllGames>(g: T): asserts this is GameCollection<Next[N], A & Record<N, T>> {
        this.store.push(g)
    }
    get<N extends keyof A>(idx: N): A[N] {
        return this.store[idx];
    }
}
```

Here we've removed all runtime checking and instead, have `add()` narrow the type of `store`.  I've had to put together `Next` so the compiler can understand that each `add()` stores a value at the next index; there's probably a better way to do that but this is just a sketch.

So here's how we'd use it.  The most painful part of assertion functions is that you have to [add explicit annotations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33580) in places you didn't have to before:

```
const store: GameCollection = new GameCollection()
// ------> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// this annotation is NECESSARY;
```

If you inspect `store`, it's type is:

```
// const store: GameCollection<0, {}>
```

Then watch what happens after each `add()`:

```
store.add(new GameA('Anton'));
store; // const store: GameCollection<1, Record<0, GameA>>
store.add(new GameB(42));
store; // const store: GameCollection<2, Record<0, GameA> & Record<1, GameB>>
```

So now, `store` can be used like this:

```
console.log('First item:', store.get(0).name); // okay
console.log('Second item:', store.get(1).name); // error!
// ------------------------------------> ~~~~
// no name on GameB
store.get(2); // error! 
// -----> ~
// 2 is not assignable to 0 | 1
```

I think this is neat, but it's probably not a great idea in general unless you plan to both create and use these collections inside related pieces of TypeScript code.  If someone hands you some unknown `GameCollection` then the compiler doesn't know anything about its contents, and you're stuck doing runtime checks again.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAnjCBxAriATgCZIDeAUGUlUvADYhRRJbgQCCpl138A9sFAAu+HPEG98AChg4ARrQCW8JKEgAuJEPwLgAcwCUpJAF8uVU2Zr1GzVgCFO3Hvy2jxUmfKUqcYWRHwAeQAzFG1oDWBff3xDEhNLC25BDGQ2WloWSCYAXltIDgAffIg7AG4KHmsmLIgAYV4MiDEFfkcnKiEJCA02fHwQNAAedMzWKAA+Co6qPgFhNwlJOMsZpEEACwUoADou-GQ8gG0AXWmZ0zWQQkJJXV6M2qgVteSt3f2IHZkoDbv9VbUS4zXQQQRDFBICAAD0EEGAhCYoyeE0kYgkkQgAHckJIdviCLooBoQMA0IYchNUAAaJAKQjQyLRAL6DSQ8ivahzIR0uFgJB5TbbPbuCBHenQs6AjoKYK4lKYXhyhR8gU5PIAchwCIgwR0EEIGpenKcm3wvBxwGxSAAov0lgAiACSOuhSF4OEE7rlsg9CKgDv0505wM5stxAEJJCqIPydEJSYglTR3PpjSbqGaLSprXbzVJnartusNsgsea9OtUoHpU5Q68DoIcPhgLzY8G64lKlyXF7PgKczjag0mi1+MtLJ8dtdblah6w2JINWxgOJgEaAdwpzPJHOSnZJAAWABMae7sxcjS+tF4uiXADEFPgeTGwGoNbSp6DBJJamxaQADPoOyqBAQZIAA9BBSArmuljcleOw3neGoAMrNPwxCvu+n6ijs36-gutIAIzAaB4FQUgIirgokBQva+AUGQFigbACBpIwASCK0AjtLM1QlBwHIzNyCzoh4ciKMooEaFoOgGEY9ZJFyAm1A4wkdKJIjidIkneFEfgBCEYQKBEPiGbEildpYCppI84wDn+SDFGpFQ2akSAAHIwl6xzEbSx60gAzLSh60gArLSABstIAOy0gAHLSACcJEASR-lIMRgVZSFWVhVlkVZTFWXxVlSVZalSDHgBUpVAwNSsCOtDNNx-BDJ5UKwvCiLmTEA7pTBXVwv6SAAEoYUQQwGTEtLIuMVJ5CQxhUhpTifL0-SDCM9nZFSABkMEds48zae4yx8a8QofKKA6nEgDAPWSx1ArWM4QsNPVIrt0CovcqCsg9nH4IITDXXSjWQM1rU8R1PlHJ5JxzUgh0TXwU2ebSKATKttZvMKU4-H8Bi1vW3Dfh1n2jQA1hAaDJmwqIShonmA2wCMnJdayNs2rbXSK3TigydUXNZJ08htJTQ2OrZ5Huw6NC1MsTtwlEALQa5rVIRjrut6-rEaWJR4OksAvCCCAbWtsWnk2nUNqoahbBjQAmuekHQaJmiihoCujlbQyDctEyTnhO7ywuS6wfwG4dp8ZQezQvbe90vtNYrMPtZlaMSIQge0n+OOh90043Lu1pqUep5BsXBwJ5RXuS37SsBzlOdTYNhco+Nk155lalF-Bl4tUht4Pk+L58jhKcHPhYKSEBIGsBR0G8NTgxDwIiHIUu6FzFhU8fjPXwEaRS+QCv9H5obqvQZr98P4-T-P1rSAAH4f2-RvQWbKisO6rY1K1xPvPU89doIBGvkgb+SAH5Ui-rfaqEMVDmyBlABQuhQDyGQOIJAAFnJZQoMYIAA)